# What is the correct currency formatting with zero amounts?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, usability-testing, usability-study

I have couple of questions:

1. I am representing decimal values in dollars in my table as follows

   ```
   $2.30

   $0.15
   ```

   I need to  know how should I represent 0 (zero) dollars. Which of the following is correct?

   ```
   $0.00

   0.00$

   0$

   $0
   ```
2. In some tables we use

   ```
   742 (9.96%)

   694 (9.48%)
   ```

   How to represent zero of zero percentage? Is this correct `0 (0.00%)`? If not how can I represent zero of zero percentage?

Comment: By using the localization settings of the client.

Comment: Local setting is for sure the best option. However you may (depending on your data) simplify the problem of units by moving the $ to the title of the column and not repeat it every line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases you have three options:

- represent 0 values in the same way you represent another values
- not represent 0 values if possible
- represent 0 values as symbol(s) when it means absence of value

Below are examples of all options.

*Option 1:*

```
#    Product    Qty    Price    Discount (%)    Gross    Net
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    Hammer     1      $2.30    $0.30 (13.04%)  $2.30    $2.00
2    Crowbar    0      $9.95    $0.00 (0.00%)   $0.00    $0.00
3    Nail       10     $0.15    $0.00 (0.00%)   $1.50    $1.50
================================================================
     Total                                      $3.80    $3.50
```

*Option 2:*

```
#    Product    Qty    Price    Discount (%)    Gross    Net
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    Hammer     1      $2.30    $0.30 (13.04%)  $2.30    $2.00
2    Crowbar           $9.99
3    Nail       10     $0.15                    $1.50    $1.50
================================================================
     Total                                      $3.80    $3.50
```

*Option 3:*

```
#    Product    Qty    Price    Discount (%)    Gross    Net
----------------------------------------------------------------
1    Hammer     1      $2.30    $0.30 (13.04%)  $2.30    $2.00
2    Crowbar    -      $9.95    -               -        -
3    Nail       10     $0.15    -               $1.50    $1.50
================================================================
     Total                                      $3.80    $3.50
```

Comment: Percentage sign on left side? never seen that. But it really makes an alignment over there.

Comment: @SurjithSM: I'm sorry that were typos, I corrected them and update my answer. SurjithSM noticed that Total Net was `%1.50`.

Comment: Oh yes. I did't see total, I just concentrated on signs :-)

Comment: @Serg - Thanks. Among the 3 we are using the top most one. thanks

Comment: Happy if it helped. I also like the option which offered by ColdCat in his comment to the question and which could be combined with option you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is based on for which country you are doing this project. So nothing is wrong or right.

**Wikipedia Says**

> In the United States, Mexico, Australia, Argentina, New Zealand, Hong
>   Kong, Pacific Island nations, and English-speaking Canada, the dollar
>   or peso symbol precedes the number, unlike most currency symbols. Five
>   dollars or pesos is written and printed as $5, whereas five cents is
>   written as 5¢. In French-speaking Canada, the dollar symbol usually
>   appears after the number (5$), although it sometimes appears in front
>   of it, or instead may even be totally absent.

In zero value, Its better to keep the same hierarchy you following for other numbers. Although Decimal value is not good. 0% is much better than 0.00%

Comment: _"In zero value, Its better to keep the same hierarchy you following for other numbers. Although Decimal value is not good. 0% is much better than 0.00%"_ - Why?

Comment: @L.Möller because decimal makes no sense in this case